# jquery radio button for multiple groups

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am using jquery for styling a radio button, but it doesn't work if a have multiple groups - meaning that only one element is styled at once right now.

I have in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".RadioClass").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(".RadioSelected:not(:checked)").removeClass("RadioSelected");
                $(this).next("label").addClass("RadioSelected");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in the html:

```
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" class="RadioClass" name="group1" >
<label id="Label1" for="Radio1" class="RadioLabelClass">Radio 1</label>
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" class="RadioClass" name="group2"/>
<label id="Label2" for="Radio2" class="RadioLabelClass">Radio 2</label>
<input id="Radio3" type="radio" class="RadioClass" name="group1"/>
<label id="Label3" for="Radio3" class="RadioLabelClass">Radio 3</label>
```

Well, where I have `group2` for example, the radio image doesn't change as it should, accordingly to jquery.
Any idea about how can I make it work for different group names?

Comment: It removes the RadioSelected from every radio button with the class RadioClass, do you only want it to remove it from the selected radio button in the current group?

Comment: exactly, it would be better to remove it only from the current group !:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".RadioClass").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
    var groupName = $(this).attr("name");
    $(".RadioClass").each(function(idx)
     {
         if($(this).attr("name") == groupName)
         {
             $(this).next("label").removeClass("RadioSelected");
         }
     });


    $(this).next("label").addClass("RadioSelected");
}
});
```

Edit: I also realised it's probably quicker to just select the elements by name.

```
$(".RadioClass").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
    var groupName = $(this).attr("name");
    $("[name='"+groupName+"']").next("label").removeClass("RadioSelected");

    $(this).next("label").addClass("RadioSelected");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

not very reliable works

```
$(".RadioClass").change(function(){ ...
```

better to replace

```
$(".RadioClass").click(function(){ ...
```